# couchdb with multiple linked documents in one doc

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

As a complete newbie to the concept of NoSQL it is giving me a hard time figuring out how to achieve something like a join with multiple linked documents.
I got a Data-Structure for a Congress in a CouchDB which is replicated to a PouchDB on a Client like:

Sessions:

```
"_id": "1",
"type": "session",
"Title": "Title of Session",
}
```

Persons:

```
"_id": "2",
"type": "Person",
"mail": "mail@mail.com",
"Names": {
    "FirstName": "Horst",
    "LastName": "Muller"
}

"_id": "3",
"type": "Person",
"mail": "mail2@mail.com",
"Names": {
    "FirstName": "Mark",
    "LastName": "Webber"
}
```

Talks:

```
"_id": "4",
"type": "presentation",
"Sessions": [
    "1"
],
"PresentationTitle": "Title of Talk",
"files": [
    {
    "Filename": "presentationfile.pptx",
    }
],
"Speakers": [
    "2",
    "3"
]
```

What I tried to achieve was an output where the documents are retrieved as if putting the doc of the linked document in the result like

```
"_id": "4",
"type": "presentation",
"Sessions": [
    "Title of Session"
],
"PresentationTitle": "Title of Talk",
"files": [
    {
    "Filename": "presentationfile.pptx",
    }
],
"Speakers": [
    {
    "FirstName": "Mark",
    "LastName": "Webber"
    },
    {
    "FirstName": "Horst",
    "LastName": "Muller"
    }
]
```

or something similar without denormalizing the data. I tried with map/reduce, Mango and pouchdb-find, but without luck. 
Is that even possible in a NoSQL-World?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a really neat feature in CouchDB called [Linked Documents](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/joins.html#linked-documents) which allows you to effectively do joins.

The gist is that if you emit an object with a `_id` property as a value, then the behavior of `include_docs=true` will fetch the linked document instead of the source document. (the docs I linked to above have a detailed example of this)

Comment: I tried those before, but as far as I could see in Fauxton the response is always a list of individual Documents. What I was looking for, was a method to put the linked documents in one document (like it would be with denormalized data) to loop easier through the JSON.

Comment: If you really want to do this at the database layer, you can use a list function to massage your JSON into any format you want, including merging multiple documents into a single one.

Comment: It really seems like the database is the wrong place for that. Maybe I think to much in SQL-Terms. I will look into merging the JSON inside the programm.

Comment: Even in SQL, you'll generally only be able to get results in 2 dimensions, where your application will have to collate anything beyond that. This really isn't much different.